# Updating and joining columns in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to SQL Access and am having a tough time with simple update and join and is becoming frustrating.

Consider I have a dataset as below

```
  Name            Sex               Age  
  Ann Z           F                 25
  Sarah H         F                 42
  Matthew B       M                 54
```

And another dataset as below

```
Name        Attended
Ann Z          Y
Trisha G       N
Laura M        Y
Matthew B      N
Erin V         N
```

And I the "Attended" field to added to table 1 based on the common column "Name" such as below-

```
Name     Sex   Age   Attended
Ann Z     F    25      Y
Sarah H   F    42      NA
Matthew B M    54      N
Trisha G  NA   NA      N
Laura M   NA   NA      Y
Erin V    NA   NA      N
```

I tried:

```
SELECT table2.Attended
FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.Name = table2.Name;
```

and then tried to update.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked-

I used an INNER JOIN to join data that were in both datasets i.e. in the above example- Ann Z & Matthew B.
I then selected all data in the second dataset (or vice versa) that IS NOT IN the first one (or vice versa) and appended it by UPDATING.